# Unable to send OS X terminal command via Java

Tags: java, iphone, macos, networking

I am trying to see if an iPhone is in tehtered mode on OS X and I am unable to send a terminal command using this code:

```
String [] cmdArray = new String[1];
cmdArray[0] = "/usr/sbin/networksetup -getinfo \"iPhone USB\"";
SendCommandForResponse(cmdArray);
```

...

```
   static String SendCommandForResponse(String[] commandArray) throws IOException {
        InputStream processOutput;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String line = " ", output = " ";
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = rt.exec(commandArray);
        processOutput = p.getInputStream();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(processOutput));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            output += line + "\n";
        }
        return output;

    }
```

When this code is ran, I receive this error:

> IOException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
>   "/usr/sbin/networksetup -getinfo "iPhone USB"": error=2, No such file
>   or directory

I am able to run this command successfully through terminal manually but when ran inside NetBeans it gives an exception. What am I doing wrong? I am new to Java on OS X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should fill the command array like this:

```
String[] cmdArray = new String[3];
cmdArray[0] = "/usr/sbin/networksetup";
cmdArray[1] = "-getinfo";
cmdArray[2] = "iPhone USB";
```

Or in short:

```
String[] cmdArray = { "/usr/sbin/networksetup", "-getinfo", "iPhone USB" };
```

- The first item should be only the command (the program to run)
- The next items are the arguments
- There is no need for extra quotes around an argument with a space in it.

When you run a command from `Terminal` directly, the *shell* interprets the command and separates it for you - which is why you need the quotes. But when you are running it from Java, the command is not handed to a shell and is not parsed. You have to do the separation of the command and the arguments yourself.

Comment: Worked. Thank you so much!